# send email through j2me application

Tags: java-me

I am having an application build using j2me lwuit.
I need to send e-mail from that app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your application smaller, I'd suggest to implement SMPT over a `SocketConnection`. For small e-mails this shall be pretty straightforward:

```
SocketConnection connection = (SocketConnection)Connector.open("socket://your.smtp.server:25");
DataInputStream is  = sc.openDataInputStream();
DataOutputStream os = sc.openDataOutputStream();
//now the SMTP chat with server
```

Using this approach may allow you to make your application to be depend only on MIDP/CLDC profiles, thus to be easier portable to other phones (at least in theory).

Comment: Then how to set from address and to address and also add an attachment??

Comment: @user206646 See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). Basically you need to send your commands and read responses from server and react appropriately. For no-attachment it's pretty straightforward - you may even use `telnet` to play a little bit with server by talking to it from your keyboard. For attachments - it's little bit more complicated, but you'll need to encode it first.

Comment: private void sendMail() {
    try {
        SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) Connector.open("socket://192.168.6.16:25");
        DataOutputStream os = sc.openDataOutputStream();

        String str="";
        str=str + "Mail From:aa@bb.com\n";
        str=str + "Mail To:aaa@bb.com \n";
        str=str + "Content-type: text/html;charset=US-ASCII";
        str=str + "Subject:Your Subjext\n";
    str=str + "Content-desciption:Mail message body\n\n";
    str=str + "Body Of Your Message";
    os.write(str.getBytes());
    os.flush();
}
}   I have written above code and it is not working

Comment: You need to do the handshake first (see the [example in Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example)). Make sure you use appropriate header names, formatting and line endings as well. Consider playing with `telnet` session first, so you'd know what actually you need to send. Then use debugger and network sniffer (e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to see if everything works as you expected. BTW: you may consider setting To: to something useful (i.e. the mailbox you can read e-mails from).

Comment: can u give me the exact code for sending mail through j2me. I just want to send a simple email.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one. Neither I have the training mail server. So that would mean up to a few job for me, however, I don't have so much time to spare. You need to work it yourself, however you're in the good way.

Comment: I hv taken snapshot from camera. J2ME gives me byte aaray. I pass this byte array as attachment in mail. But I not getting proper image. Any idea?

Comment: You need to encode it before sending. I guess it's going to be Base64 encoding, but you need to check it first.

Comment: but outputstream. write only accepts byte array. So how to encode a byte array and convert it again into byte array

Comment: @user206646 By encoding I meant converting your binary byte array into some MIME compatible form (i.e. plain ASCII characters) like [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Hi find the link its working fine. You can send mail with attachment.

http://itminds-usefullinks.blogspot.com/2011/12/sending-mail-from-j2me-app-wihtout-web_01.html

its really helps You....